# Can't comment on a facebook group post using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api to comment on a post made by me in a facebook group that i am admin of. I am getting the following error:

```
{u'error': {u'message': u'(#3) Publishing comments through the API is only available for page access tokens', u'code': 3, u'type': u'OAuthException', u'fbtrace_id': u'Fy1DWoFqblz'}}
```

How do i get away from this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the changelog:

> 90-day Deprecations in Graph API v2.10
>
> POST and DELETE operations for the /{comment-id} node and the
> /{object-id}/comments edge will now be restricted to Pages with valid
> page access tokens.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_10

Answer (score 0):

According to the facebook documentation after, 90 days i wont be able to reply comments using the API. It is right?

Checkout the facebook documentation comment:

> 90-day Deprecations in Graph API v2.10
>
> POST and DELETE operations for the /{comment-id} node and the
>   /{object-id}/comments edge will now be restricted to Pages with valid
>   page access tokens.